# Salesforce Domain Name Change to Our company Name?

Tags: lightning, community, url, custom-domain

We are planning to create a custom domain to our Client org, as they requested client want like `https://ClientName.ProductName.salesforce.com` instead of `https://ClientName.my.salesforce.com`. Can we Make it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [My Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=5) documentation says you cannot. You must have the `my` and can't have the dot.

One reason for this may be that if this naming pattern was open:

```
https://ClientName.ProductName.salesforce.com
```

naming could be used that would be hard to distinguish from a direct product offering from Salesforce.